# Why should you use the Doctrine Query Result Cache?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

At the company where I work I have the job to research wether they should use the Doctrine Query Result cache and if they should then I need to teach everyone to use it.

I am considering the use of this feature in Doctrine. We are already using DQL->SQL cache and the mapping driver cache. But it seems that MySQL already caches result sets even for prepared statements cause we are using a version higher then MySQL Server 5.1.17.

According to [this](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/01/29/how-mysql-query-cache-works-with-transactions/) page it seems that InnoDB has problems with result set caching for transactions. I am not 100% sure but it seems that Doctrine uses transactions for database mutations therefore it might that caching which MySQL does is not appriopiate.

But the actual question is, does the Doctrine Query Result cache has an advantage over falling back to the MySQL resultset cache and is it worth it?

Offcourse I do understand that for other database systems this function could be more usefull but my current scope is now MySQL.

Our DBA is sayng that a single developer shouldn't be responsible for caching..

Comment: Doctrine Result Caching will store the results as entities. This will save you time on: 1) Fetching data, 2) hydration. So even if your results are cached in mysql server, you will still save some time / memory in hydration.

Comment: It's not a true. From Doctrine 2.1 it keeps cache before hydration (pay attention on that, because there are few divergent statements about it in the documentation). I've notice sth like hydration cache somewhere (i don't remember if it was in the code or in docs), but i can't say much more about it now.